# Nested Lodash ForEach

Tags: node.js, object, coffeescript, performance, lodash

I have an in memory database that is fairly deep, I think, I have found the best implementation of the code, if anyone has a better way to do a double forEach loop in lodash or if I am using it wrong somehow would be great to know.

The Object:

```
smallDB = {
  user1:{
    permissions:[],
    locations:[
      {ip:'0.0.0.0',messages:[]},
      {ip:'',messages:[]}
    ]
  },
  user2:{
    permissions:[],
    locations:[
      {ip:'0.0.0.0',messages:[]},
      {ip:'0.0.1.0',messages:[{mid:'a unique id','user':'the sender',message:'the text of the message'}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

sending a message I use:

```
ld.forEach smallDB, (a)->
  ld.forEach a.locations, (b)->
    b.messages.push {mid,user,message}
```

I just wanted to make sure this is the best way to add messages into the mini database for all the users in smallDB and in all their locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one very easy optimization you can do **if** the objects you create with `{mid,user,message}` are **immutable**:

```
record = {mid,user,message}
ld.forEach smallDB, (a)->
  ld.forEach a.locations, (b)->
    b.messages.push record
```

If you do this, you save yourself the cost of creating a new object each time you push. Dropping the `forEach` in favor of using `for` would also make things faster.

It would be further optimizable by allowing a more direct access to the arrays that you access as `b.messages` in your original code, but this would complicate addition and removal of users or locations. I don't think is worth it unless proved by profiling that it is *not* a premature optimization.

Comment: they are immutable so +1 for that :) but I thought I heard/saw that lodash is faster than coffeescript's for loop?

Comment: I admit I was thinking about JavaScript loops written by hand. However, after using the live [CoffeeScript compiler](http://coffeescript.org/) (the "Try Coffeescript" button) and inspecting how CoffeeScript converts its loops to JS, I'm not seeing anything dramatically different from a JS loop crafted by hand. If you have a reference for the claim you heard or saw, I'd be curious to see it.

Comment: There are lots of loop speed tests on `jsperf`.  `lodash` often is fastest because it adapts itself to the browser engine.  In some cases it uses the native `each`, in others it uses a `while` loop.  Coffeescript always uses `for` loop, so it usually does well, but not quite as good as `lodash`.

Comment: @hpaulj please point us to a specific jsperf test that shows what you say.

Comment: I saw this one... http://jsperf.com/prime-vs-underscore-vs-lodash/3  
I know it's not the forEach but it is a coffeescript loosing by nearly  2x the length of time to complete.

Comment: In that `filter` example, `lodash` is clearly better on Chrome, but not on other browsers.  I wonder how `lodash` implements it.  `coffeewcript` uses a conditional `push`.

Comment: @hpaulj well I am looking for node.js so I am actually going to have to run my own tests

Comment: The setup for the `filter` example looks wrong.  It creates `array=['xxxxx...']`.  I changed it to use `split('')`.  Now `coffeescript` is only 25% slower than `lodash`.

Comment: Since `node.js` uses `V8`, the Chromium tests should apply.

Comment: @hpaulj when I run it on my chrome it says it's 73% slower using coffeescript

Comment: @hpaulj The test you linked to is misleading. It relies on `array` not having been declared with `var`. I've created two tests from the one you linked. The [first](http://jsperf.com/coffeescript-for-vs-underscore-each-vs-jquery-each/22) adds a new CoffeeScript test at the end that does `var array = window.array`.  This new test is the fastest.

Comment: @hpaulj The [second](http://jsperf.com/coffeescript-for-vs-underscore-each-vs-jquery-each/21) has the *same* set of tests as the one you linked but creates the array with `var array = ...` instead of `window.array = `. So *all* tests benefit from the change. Here too the CoffeeScript code is fastest.

Comment: just ran the coffeescript vs lodash. for loop was the best, lodash's each -30%. Chrome 41.